# How to develop a SOAP API as a guest user

Tags: api, rest-api, soap, soap-api-v2, web-services

I am trying to developing a SOAP API.

For first I created a module like this **`app\code\MyVendor\MyModule`** in which I created **`etc\module.xml`**, **`etc\webapi.xml`** and **`etc\di.xml`**.
Then I created my API Interface in **`app\code\MyVendor\MyModule\Api`** and the relative model in **`app\code\MyVendor\MyModule\Model`**, modified di.xml setting the preference for my Model and then tried to consume it.

The problem is the following:

Using an interface **without** parameters in the method everything works fine, when I add just one parameter in the methods of my interface and model I cant access WSDL neither invoke WS.

The error I got is "**Consumer is not authorized to access %resources**"

### Interface Code

```
<?php


namespace Lutech\ProrductService\Api;

interface ProductServiceManagementInterface {


    /**
     * @param string $param
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProductService($param);
}
```

### Model Code

```
<?php


namespace Lutech\ProductService\Model;

class ProductServiceManagement {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getProductService($param)
    {
        return 'hello api GET return the $param ' ;
    }
}
```

### di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Lutech\ProductService\Api\ProductServiceManagementInterface" type="Lutech\ProductService\Model\ProductServiceManagement"/>
</config>
```

### webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route method="GET" url="/V1/lutech-productservice2/productservice">
        <service class="Lutech\ProductService\Api\ProductServiceManagementInterface" method="getProductService"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```